# Update brew-installed applications when migrating from Intel Macbook to Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-silicon, migration-assistant

Just yesterday, I've migrated from a Macbook Air from 2015 (with Intel-based processor) to a Macbook Air with M1. I've used the migration assistant for this and was pretty surprised that everything, including applications and settings, was properly migrated.

Most of the applications were installed using brew, and running `brew upgrade` on the M1 Macbook caused an error first. After having installed Rosetta through `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`, brew was running perfectly. But I wonder how the best procedure for my applications might look like. Would later versions of them be upgraded from Intel-based applications to ARM-based when running `brew upgrade`, or do I need to change any configuration manually?

Comment: I assume this is about Homebrew. Please ask a separate question for other applications

Comment: Yes, this is for applications that were installed using Homebrew. Thanks for marking a duplicate, that already answers parts of my question, but not the main part: do I really need to reinstall anything? Would a later update of any application move that application from Intel-based to ARM-based? Because using Rosetta, I don't see any immediate need to change anything

Comment: Homebrew doesn‘t auto-update to ARM code, you even can have both an Intel installation in /usr/local and an ARM version in /opt/homebrew.

Comment: @NicoHaase The linked answer has explicit instructions on how to move your Intel install over to ARM.  Re moving from Intel to ARM, that is your choice, but binaries you install with Homebrew will be running in Intel emulation.